# how to List View items in two columns instead of one column in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

my current implementation is retrieving items from database using Future Builder widget and then display it in a list view , what I'm trying to achieve is how I make the display of items in two column instead of one?
here is my code that preview items in a vertical single column  :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Product>>(
      future: fetchProducts(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData)
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        else {
          print (snapshot.data.length) ;
          return Container(
            child: Scrollbar(
              isAlwaysShown: true,
              controller: _scroll,
              child: ListView.builder(
                controller: _scroll,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return WidgetProduct(snapshot.data[index]);
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: check `GridView.builder` then

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: ListView.builder create columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51141299/flutter-listview-builder-create-columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@pskink is right you can use GridView.builder()

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ListView.separated(
      separatorBuilder: (context, int) {
        return Divider(color: Colors.black,);
      },
     // shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return GridView.count(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          childAspectRatio: 2.0,
          children: List.generate(6, (index) {
            return Center(
              child: RaisedButton(
                onPressed: (){},
                color: Colors.greenAccent,
                child: Text(
                  'item no : $index',
                ),
              ),
            );
          }),
        );
      },
      itemCount: 4,
    ));
  }
```